# Loading XML via jQuery for Google Maps API V3

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**UPDATE:**
Fatigue onset user error, not the code itself, turned out to be the problem. I simply called the `initialize()` function twice by mistake. I'll leave this post up as the code snippet may be of some use to others hoping to consume XML data for a Google Map via jQuery.

I am loading map marker coordinates and infoWindow content from an XML file via jQuery for Google Maps (API V3). Everything appears to be working fine<strike>, except for the fact that every marker is added twice</strike>.

Here is my JS:

```
google.load("maps", "3",  {other_params:"sensor=false"});
google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");

var infowindow;
var map;

function initialize() {

// Specify center of the map
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.781,-107.402);

// Customize map appearance
var mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT},
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoom: 3
} // end mapOptions();

// Load the Google map into the #mapCanvas div
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);

jQuery.get("iphorm/test.xml", function(data) {
  jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
    var eachMarker = jQuery(this);
    var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Latitude").text()),
        parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Longitude").text())
    );
    var name = eachMarker.find("Name").text();
    var content = eachMarker.find("Content").text();
    var html = "<div class='info-blob'>" + name + "<br />" + content + "</div>";

    var marker = addMarker(html, markerCoords);

    });
  });
} // end initialize();

// Create a marker for each XML entry
function addMarker(html, markerCoords) {

// Place the new marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map,
    position: markerCoords
}); // end place the new marker

// Add event listener. On marker click, close all open infoWindows open current infoWindow.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}); // end add event listener

// Display marker
return marker;

} // end addMarker();

// On page lod, initialize the map
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <markers>
        <marker>
            <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
            <Content>A bit of content goes here.</Content>
            <Latitude>53.69629</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-123.925437</Longitude>
        </marker>
        <marker>
            <Name>Joe Smith</Name>
            <Content>A bit of content goes here.</Content>
            <Latitude>55.627598</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-115.136375</Longitude>
        </marker>
</markers>
```

Obviously, each `<marker>` element from the XML should only be grabbed once for the map. <strike>Any ideas on how to fix this error?</strike> **Edit:** Code works as intended.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer

Comment: @refhat It was a question, but is now an answer. My rep isn't high enough yet for me to answer my own question. As soon as I can (end of the day) I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS and the XML are both functioning properly. I simply called the `initialize()` function twice by mistake.