# downloadUrl function not working for creating google map locator with opencart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using opencart to develop http://www.goskitz.com.au/index.php?route=information/dealers

In the dealers.php file there is a function called query() which will search postcodes from the database to get the store locations results and I outputted to XML format. For example, if I typed 3000 and select Melbourne, the xml output would be:

### function query():

```
public function query(){
        // the query coding part is removed
        // Output to XML  
        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
        $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
        $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

         header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
         // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

         foreach($result as $key => $li){   
         // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
         $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
         $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
         $newnode->setAttribute("name",$li['name']);
         $newnode->setAttribute("address", $li['address']);
         $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $li['lat']);
         $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $li['lng']);
         $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $li['distance']);
         }

         echo $dom->saveXML();
     }

}
```

### Output

```
<markers><marker name="Harvey Norman BIG BUYS" address="Shop 9&amp;11 Ground Level Springvale Homemaker Centre 917 Princes Highway Springval VIC 3171" lat="-37.927456" lng="145.143845" distance="19.74128375361586"></marker>....blahblah... <markers>
```

Then I found the downloadurl function is not working, no matter what url I put, nothing happens. Why would that happen?

Any idea would be grateful.

I have paste the javascript in http://pastebin.com/yu0bX3vz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code you are showing here is responsible for the generation of the XML.
The generated XML contains the marker data, which needs to be parsed and handed over to Google Maps API, in order to draw the markers.

The first thing you might want to do is, to get one marker working, then level up to multiple markers. Just try to get the XML right and the marker(s) to be drawn on the map. 
The map must be initialized before you try to add marker(s).

If that works out, proceed to load the marker XML dynamically via jQuery.
Because you are already working with jQuery, i suggest to drop the downloadURL() function, in favor of a simple jQuery Ajax .get() request with an added success function, for parsing the incomming response XML.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "markers.xml", // xml source: either static xml file or xml generated by php
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml // parse the marker xml
  });
});

// the idea is: from xml -> to var "location" -> addMarker(location)
function parseXml(xml)
{
  // foreach marker extract the xml data (lat,long,...)
  $(xml).find("marker").each(function(index){

     // and assign to a new location var
     var location.lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
     var location.long = $(this).find('long').text();
     var location.name = $(this).find('name').text();

     // then use this data to add the marker
     addMarker(location);
  )
}    

function addMarker(location)
{
    // the marker is a "point" on the map defined by it's lat/long
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng); 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position:point,
       map: map,
       title: location.name
    }); 
};
```

If you need to bind an info window or something, which pops up, when clicked on the marker icon, 
then please search for bindInfoWindow() in this article https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

I think, this is the origin of this downloadURL() function you got, but in this tutorial, they don't use jQuery, like you do.

This question might be of help too: [Loading XML via jQuery for Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8771690/1163786)